# Android SDK Manager can't download new files

Tags: android

I was trying to get the latest android sources (5.0, just to see how it looked), but then, when I tried to download the sources from Android SDK, it gives me an error, saying that the **local** URL is not found. Here is the log:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 5
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 5
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.3.1, API 18, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.4W.2, API 20, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 19, revision 6
  Found Samples for SDK API 20, revision 3
  Found Samples for SDK API 21, revision 4
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 21
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 20
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
  Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 20, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 3
  Found Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 10
  Found Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Android Support Library, revision 21.0.3
  Found Android Support Repository, revision 11
  Found Google Repository, revision 15
  Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
  Found Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12
  Found Google Play services, revision 22
  Found Google USB Driver, revision 11
  Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
  Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)
  Found Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
  Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  Found Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Found Android Support Library, revision 19.1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
  Found Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 11
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 5.2
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 16, revision 4
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 4
  Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20, revision 4
  Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
  Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
  Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Found Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 10
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 5
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 5
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.3.1, API 18, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.4W.2, API 20, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 19, revision 6
  Found Samples for SDK API 20, revision 3
  Found Samples for SDK API 21, revision 4
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 21
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 20
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
  Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 20, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 3
  Found Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 10
  Found Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Android Support Library, revision 21.0.3
  Found Android Support Repository, revision 11
  Found Google Repository, revision 15
  Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
  Found Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12
  Found Google Play services, revision 22
  Found Google USB Driver, revision 11
  Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
  Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)
  Found Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
  Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  Found Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Found Android Support Library, revision 19.1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
  Found Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 11
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 5.2
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 16, revision 4
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 4
  Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20, revision 4
  Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
  Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
  Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
  Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Found Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 10
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r24.0.2-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 21
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\platform-tools_r21-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\docs-21_r01.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-21_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 21, revision 4
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-21_r04.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\sources-21_r01.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 21.0.3
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\support_r21.0.3.zip (Access is denied)
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I don't understand the problem and I would like to understand what is going on and how to fix it.

--EDIT--
I forgot to mention: I am on Windows 8.1 and using Android Studio.

Comment: Windows is by far the least suited platform for android work, but as a throwaway guess from someone who has zero interest in trying to do it, you may need to do this as an administrator or choose a user-owned directory to install into.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to execute your sdk manager with administrator privileges / account.
It seems that the file exists even if it says that URL is not found, it just simply can't access it because the sdk manager isn't elevated enough.

URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r24.0.2-windows.zip **(Access is denied)**

Same thing for every lines so it's probably just a rights prolem.

Comment: your answer helped me .and saved my lot of time.big Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Run the app as administrator, I had the same problem. Just do it and it's gonna work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but ran the sdk manager as administrator and things worked for me in windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after running as administrator it worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

- Click Window key
- Search "SDK Manager"
- Right Click on SDK Manager
- Click ON Run Administrator.