# install Android SDK tool manually - Google Play Service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install the Google Play Services SDK tool through the Android SDK Component installer.

The download starts well, but then fails after a while.

> Packages to install: 
>   - Google Play services (extras;google;google_play_services)
>
> Preparing "Install Google Play services (revision: 49)". Downloading
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_v16_1_rc09.zip
>   An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play services:
>   Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_v16_1_rc09.zip':
>   Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 15456884 bytes. ,
>   response: 200 OK. "Install Google Play services (revision: 49)"
>   failed. Failed packages:
>   - Google Play services (extras;google;google_play_services)

I managed to externally download the package through the provided link below:

> https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_v16_1_rc09.zip

Is there a way I can manually install this package?

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829942/android-sdk-manager-cant-download-new-files

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is:

1. Run Android Studio as Administrator.
2. Re-run the update.